# Limit with non square roots without l'Hôpital’s rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to calculate the following limit:

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x+x^3}$ without the l'Hôpital rule.

This limit can be found in Kitchen's book Calculus of one Variable, exercise 5t), section 3-5, during that section the book has substitution techniques and rationalization, but the latter is only done when both roots are square roots, so if there is a specific factorization that works, I also would thank how to find it.

By now i have tried the substitution $u=1+x^2$ and $u=1-x$, but none has got me anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Outline of Strategy:** Write $\sqrt[3]{1+x^2} - \sqrt[4]{1-2x}= \sqrt[3]{1+x^2} - 1 + 1 - \sqrt[4]{1-2x}= \dfrac{x^2}{....}+ \dfrac{2x}{...}= x\left(\dfrac{1}{...}+\dfrac{2x}{...}\right)$, and for the denominator: $x+x^3 = x(1+x^2)$. Then the $x$ got canceled out and you can plug $x = 0$ into the expression to get the limit. You no longer have the indeterminate form. Note that the first part uses $a - b = \dfrac{a^3 - b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$,and the second part uses $a - b = \dfrac{a^4 - b^4}{a^3 + a^2b+ ab^2 + b^3}$.

Comment: Very nice solution.  (+1)

Answer (score 3):

If you are bored, you may use the analogous identity for the $12$th power:

$$\begin{align*}
a^{12} - b^{12} &= (a-b)(a^{11} + a^{10}b + a^9b^2 + \cdots + b^{11})\\
&= (a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{11} a^{11-i}b^i
\end{align*}$$

Let $a = \sqrt[3]{1+x^2}$ and $b = \sqrt[4]{1-2x}$. Then the required limit is

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2} - \sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x+x^3}
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^{12}-b^{12}}{(x+x^3) \sum_{i=0}^{11} a^{11-i}b^i}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x^2)^{4}-(1-2x)^{3}}{(x+x^3) \sum_{i=0}^{11} a^{11-i}b^i}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+4x^2+6x^4+4x^6+x^8 - 1+6x-12x^2 +8x^3}{(x+x^3) \sum_{i=0}^{11} a^{11-i}b^i}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(4x+6x^3+4x^5+x^7 +6-12x +8x^2)}{x(1+x) \sum_{i=0}^{11} a^{11-i}b^i}\\
&= \frac{6}{12} = \frac 12
\end{align*}$$

because $\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{i=0}^{11} a^{11-i}b^i = 12$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, you have :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x(x^2+1)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac {1-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x}\end{align}
$$

Let $\thinspace 1-2x=u^4$ as $u\to 1$, then you obtain :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{u\to 1}\frac {2(1-u)}{1-u^4}&=\lim_{u\to 1}\frac {2(1-u)}{(1-u)(1+u)(1+u^2)}\\
&=\frac 12\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

---

We used the following facts :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x(x^2+1)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x}\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sqrt [3]{1+x^2}-1}{x}&=\lim_{u\to 1}\sqrt {\frac {(u-1)^2}{u^3-1}}\\
&=0\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Comment: (+1) The second limit with $x\to0$ is also $-1$ times the derivative of $\sqrt[4]{1-2x}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: In the numerators of the first equation, how $\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}$ becomes $1$ is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: The first equation is valid, I convinced myself by converting $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x}=\frac {\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-1}{x}+ \frac {1-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x}$$
(similar to how the [first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676649/89922) did), and the first fraction on the RHS tends to $0$. Proving the first fraction tends to $0$ would take as much effort as the remaining steps. It was also not immediately obvious to me why one chose to replace $\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}$ by $1$, but not replace $\sqrt[4]{1-2x}$ by $1$. (Ans: because the second fraction on the RHS doesn't tend to $0$)

Comment: Just to know I'm getting all right, we are ignoring the term $(x^2+1)$ because it tends to one as x goes to 0? Aren't we implicitly assuming the limit exist doing that?

Comment: As $\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-1}{x}$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac {1-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x}$ both exist, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x}$ exists as a sum of two limits. Together with $\lim_{x\to0}(x^2+1)$ exists and non-zero, the limit in the question exists as a fraction of two limits.

Comment: @peterwhy So I added  the "facts".